# How to change a Android (JsonProperty["value"]) value in C#?

Tags: c#, android, json

```
public class RootObject
{

[JsonProperty("585709" )]
public List<SummonerId> SummonerId { get; set; }

}
```

I have a class that uses the JsonProperty["585709"] for my JSON Api call.
This is exactly what I want but.. the problem I am facing is , The property has to change according to the User's Id number.

What I've tried :

This seems to work however when the Json call is made the value searches for the original value "585709".

```
       public class CustomDataContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
        {
        public static readonly CustomDataContractResolver Instance = new CustomDataContractResolver();

        protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
        {
            var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
            if (property.DeclaringType == typeof(RootObject))
            {
                if (property.PropertyName.Equals("585709", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    property.PropertyName = "569099";
                }
            }
            return property;
        }
     }


  var prop = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(r, new JsonSerializerSettings {     ContractResolver = CustomDataContractResolver.Instance });
        var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(request)
```

Is there a way I can change the value of JsonProperty for the Class?

Comment: Deserialize to a `Dictionary<string, List<SummonerId>>` or `Dictionary<long, List<SummonerId>>`.  See [Create a strongly typed c# object from json object with ID as the name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34213566).

Comment: var dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<long, <List<SummonerId>>(request);

what is the correct syntax??

Comment: It's `var dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<long, List<SummonerId>>>(request);`

Comment: how can I use the values in dictionary?

Comment: You can loop through them as shown here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x.aspx.  See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx.  The user ids will be deserialized as the dictionary keys.

Comment: Thank you dbc, You have helped me alot and solved the issues I was facing. Thank you again!