# How can I deserialize complex json repsonse into easy-to-deserialize structure using Newtonsoft.Json?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Having this strange-looking json response:

```
{
    "invoices":{
       "0":{
          "invoice":{
             "id":"420",
             "invoicecontents":{
                "0":{
                   "invoicecontent":{
                      "name":"Here's the name of the content 0"
                   }
                },
                "1":{
                   "invoicecontent":{
                      "name":"Here's the name of the content 1"
                   }
                }
             }
          }
       },
       "1":{
         "invoice":{
            "id":"420",
            "invoicecontents":{
               "0":{
                  "invoicecontent":{
                     "name":"Here's the name of the content 0"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      },
       "parameters":{
          "limit":"3",
          "page":"1",
          "total":"420"
       }
    },
    "status":{
       "code":"OK"
    }
 }
```

How do I change the structure into this easy-to-deserialize one?

```
{
   "invoices":[
      {
         "id":"420",
         "invoicecontents":[
            {
               "name":"Here's the name of the content 0"
            },
            {
               "name":"Here's the name of the content 1"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":"420",
         "invoicecontents":[
            {
               "name":"Here's the name of the content 0"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I'd like to deserialize into List of Invoices as below

```
class Invoice {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("invoicecontents")]
    public InvoiceContent[] Contents { get; set; }

    class InvoiceContent {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

There's no problem with getting the status code or parameters, I simply do this:

```
var parsed = JObject.Parse(jsonInvoices);

var statusCode = parsed?["status"]?["code"]?.ToString();
var parameters = parsed?["invoices"]?["parameters"]?;
```

The real problem starts when I'm trying to achieve easy-to-deserialize json structure I've mentioned before. I've tried something like this:

```
var testInvoices = parsed?["invoices"]?
    .SkipLast(1)
    .Select(x => x.First?["invoice"]);
```

But I can't manage to "repair" invoicecontents/invoicecontent parts.
My goal is to deserialize and store the data.

Comment: so you want to change the json string from the hard version using string manipulation into the easy version before deserialization, correct?

Comment: I would take the JSON as is and deserialize the property names that appear strange to you into a dictionary. E.g. the object value of `"invoices"` can be deserialized into a `Dictionary<string, Invoice>` if `Invoice.Contents` has the type `Dictionary<string, InvoiceContent>`. The properties `"0"`, `"1"`, etc. will be the keys of those dictionaries. If you really, really want your model to look like your proposal then I'd make a second model hierarchy and map to it via C# code.

Comment: But your are right that in this particular case the JSON is weird. The index properties `"0"` etc. add no additional information that couldn't have been transmitted by using a simple JSON array.

Comment: You could design a data model for your desired JSON, and for each list that is serialized as a dictionary, use `ListToDictionaryConverter<T>` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41559688/3744182) to [Display JSON object array in datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41553379/3744182).

Comment: @dbc I'll check that out and see the performance differences, but for now I'm happy it's working :) I agree that dictionary sounds more appropriate tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't JSON.

JavaScript Object Notation literally describes *Objects*. What you have here is the punchline of a joke that starts out with: "A SQL JOIN, a StringBuilder, and a couple for loops walk into a bar..."

As others have demonstrated, JObject is great for working with JSON that would be impractical to define as classes. You can use Linq to navigate through it, but **JSONPath Expressions** can be much simpler.

Example 1: Let's get the status code.

`var status = parsed.SelectToken(".status.code").Value<string>();`

Example 2: Let's 'deserialize' our invoices.

```
public string Invoice 
{ 
  public string Id { get; set; } 
  public List<string> Content { get; set; }
}

public List<Invoice> GetInvoices(string badJson)
{
  var invoices = JObject.Parse(badJson).SelectTokens(".invoices.*.invoice");
  var results = new List<Invoice>();
  foreach (var invoice in invoices)
  {
    results.Add(new Invoice()
    {
      Id = invoice.Value<string>("id"),
      Contents = invoice.SelectTokens(".invoicecontents.*.invoicecontent.name")
        .Values<string>().ToList()
      // Note: JToken.Value<T> & .Values<T>() return nullable types
    });
  }
  return results;
}
```

Comment: SelectTokens() is a cool idea, thanks! Well, as weird and incorrect as it looks, it is still a valid JSON file - and sadly I have to work with it.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
     var jsonParsed = JObject.Parse(json);
    
    var invoices = ((JObject) jsonParsed["invoices"]).Properties()
    .Select(x => (JObject) x.Value["invoice"] ).Where(x => x != null)
    .Select(s => new Invoice
    {
        Id = s.Properties().First(x => x.Name == "id").Value.ToString(),
        Contents = ((JObject)s.Properties().First(x => x.Name == "invoicecontents").Value).Properties()
        .Select(x => (string) x.Value["invoicecontent"]["name"]).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

and I simplified your class too, I don't see any sense to keep array of classes with one string, I think it should be just array of strings

```
public class Invoice
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public List<string> Contents { get; set; }
}
```

result

```
[
  {
    "Id": "420",
    "Contents": [
      "Here's the name of the content 0",
      "Here's the name of the content 1"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "420",
    "Contents": [
      "Here's the name of the content 0"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works! Of course I do have more properties in the invoice class that I'll need to fill up from incoming json, but I think it's more than a good way to do it as you suggested :)