# Deserialize JSON with numbers as property names

Tags: c#, json

I have JSON like this:

```
{"rows":
    {
        "1":{"rowNumber":1,"productID":"100"},
        "2":{"rowNumber":2,"productID":"101"},
        "3":{"rowNumber":3,"productID":"102"}
    }
}
```

I need to build domain model.

For example:

```
class Row 
{
    public int rowNumber{get; set;}
    public string productID{get; set;}
}
```

Root object

```
class RootObject
{
   public ? ? rows {get; set;}
}
```

What kind of type have to be rows propperty?

Comment: What do you mean by 'with digits as type'? your question is not clear

Comment: Make your `"rows"` property be a `Dictionary<string, Row>`.  See [Create a strongly typed c# object from json object with ID as the name](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34213566/3744182) and [How can I parse a JSON string that would cause illegal C# identifiers?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24536564/3744182).

Comment: -> dbc: Place your comment as answear, I'll mark as correct answear

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is

```
public Dictionary<int, Row> rows { get; set; }
```

and use

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

for deserialization. Where JsonConvert is from [Newtonsoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are looking for either int type or int32 type:

```
//Assumes you are using Newtonsoft JSON Nuget Package

List<int> products = null;

products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<int>>(json);
```

Should work - but all code you find on StackOverflow should be looked at as pseudo code. this should at least point you in the right direction. Hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear,But this can be useful

```
public class Account
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Roles { get; set; }
};
string json = @"{
   'Email': 'james@example.com',
   'Active': true,
   'CreatedDate': '2013-01-20T00:00:00Z',
  'Roles': [
     'User',
     'Admin'
   ]
 }";

Account account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(json);

Console.WriteLine(account.Email);
```