# Unwanted Json tags - How to remove them?

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have the following Json:

```
{  
   "sport":{  
      "1":{  
         "id":1,
         "competition":{  
            "11190":{  
               "id":11190,
               "name":"Premier League - Mujeres",
               "game":{  
                  "6898263":{  
                     "id":6898263,
                     "market":{  
                        "81346840":{  
                           "id":81346840,
                           "name":"Resultado del Partido",
                           "type":"P1XP2",
                           "event":{  
                             "237487499":{  
                                 "id":237487499,
                                 "name":"W1",
                                 "type":"P1",
                                 "price":1.006
                              },
                              "237487500":{  
                                 "id":237487500,
                                 "name":"X",
                                 "type":"X",
                                 "price":17.0
                              },
                              "237487501":{  
                                 "id":237487501,
                                 "name":"W2",
                                 "type":"P2",
                                 "price":21.0
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The tags which are at the start of every child element i.e "1","11190","6898263","81346840" are unwanted and I want to remove them from json. .Net consider it as a class name and don't deserialize it to the my class objects.  these tags are random numbers i.e. these are IDs of the object in them.
please guide with C#.Net code.

Comment: How did you generate this JSON?

Comment: Its coming as a response of my request to a webSocket API.

Comment: The easiest think to do would be to deserialize to a `Dictionary<long, T>` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34213724/3744182) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24536564/3744182).

Comment: great! it worked. thanks a lot for your help :)
Previously i was trying list KeyValuePair but it was not working...

how can i mark this comment as solution?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest think to do would be to deserialize to a Dictionary as suggested here and here.

thanks @dbc for your help on this.