# Deserialize nested JObject with the key into List

Tags: c#, json.net

I need to deserialize a json back to object instance using Newtonsoft.Json.

However, it is a list type object and the key of the entry is useful to me.

I don't know how to deserialize automatically without mapping the fields one by one manually.

Here is the response:

```
{
    coins: {
        365Coin: {
            id: 74,
            tag: "365",
            algorithm: "Keccak",
            lagging: true,
            listed: false,
            status: "No available stats",
            testing: false
        },
        Aiden: {
            id: 65,
            tag: "ADN",
            algorithm: "Scrypt-OG",
            lagging: true,
            listed: false,
            status: "No available stats",
            testing: false
        },
        Adzcoin: {
            id: 157,
            tag: "ADZ",
            algorithm: "X11",
            lagging: false,
            listed: false,
            status: "Active",
            testing: false
        }
        ... [With various key representing the name of coins]
    }
}
```

The full response: https://whattomine.com/calculators.json

My best guess of the class is somethings like:

```
internal class WhatToMineCalculatorsResponse
{
    // Should be Dictionary???
    [JsonProperty("coins")]
    public IList<WhatToMineCalculatorResponse> Coins { get; set; }
}

internal class WhatToMineCalculatorResponse
{
    // I want the key set in this field
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("tag")]
    public string Symbol { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("algorithm")]
    public string Algo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("listed")]
    public bool IsListed { get; set; }
}
```

Note that I want the key included in my class but not as the key of a dictionary. It's hard to retrieve the key later.

Comment: Instead of a list, use `public Dictionary<string, WhatToMineCalculatorResponse> Coins { get; set; }` as shown in [How can I parse a JSON string that would cause illegal C# identifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24536564/3744182) or [Create a strongly typed c# object from json object with ID as the name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34213724/3744182)

Comment: @dbc How about I want the key including in my class but not as the key of a dictionary. It's hard to retrieve the key later.

Comment: Then you'll need to create a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm).

Comment: I see. It means I can't do it automatically using the existing `JsonConverter`. I have to transform the dictionary to my wanted list after the deserialization.

Comment: I am thinking if there are any attributes can do it automatically for me.

Comment: Not purely through attributes.  In its [Serialization Guide](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationguide.htm#Dictionarys) Newtonsoft explains that dictionaries and hashtables get mapped to JSON objects, but all other enumerables, lists and arrays get mapped to JSON arrays.  You want to override this basic mapping, and so will need a custom converter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot specify entirely through attributes that an `IList<T>` for some `T` should be serialized as a JSON object.  As explained in its [Serialization Guide](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationguide.htm#Dictionarys), Newtonsoft maps dictionaries and hashtables to JSON objects, but maps all other enumerables, lists and arrays to JSON arrays.  Instead, you will have to use a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm).

First, define the following converter:

```
internal class WhatToMineCalculatorResponseListConverter : KeyedListToJsonObjectConverterBase<WhatToMineCalculatorResponse>
{
    protected override string KeyPropertyUnderlyingName => nameof(WhatToMineCalculatorResponse.Name);
}

public abstract class KeyedListToJsonObjectConverterBase<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        if (objectType.IsArray)
            return false;
        return typeof(IList<T>).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    protected abstract string KeyPropertyUnderlyingName { get; }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // Get the key property name from the underlying name
        var itemContract = serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(typeof(T)) as JsonObjectContract;
        if (itemContract == null)
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("type {0} is not serialized as a JSON object"));
        var keyProperty = itemContract.Properties.Where(p => p.UnderlyingName == KeyPropertyUnderlyingName).SingleOrDefault();
        if (keyProperty == null)
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Key property {0} not found", KeyPropertyUnderlyingName));

        // Validate initial token.
        if (reader.SkipComments().TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.StartObject)
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Unexpected token {0} at {1}", reader.TokenType, reader.Path));

        // Allocate the List<T>.  (It might be some subclass of List<T>, so use the default creator.
        var list = existingValue as ICollection<T> ?? (ICollection<T>)serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType).DefaultCreator();

        // Process each key/value pair.
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.TokenType)
            {
                case JsonToken.Comment:
                    break;
                case JsonToken.EndObject:
                    return list;
                case JsonToken.PropertyName:
                    {
                        // Get the name.
                        var name = (string)reader.Value;
                        reader.ReadAndAssert();
                        // Load the object
                        var jItem = JObject.Load(reader);
                        // Add the name property
                        jItem.Add(keyProperty.PropertyName, name);
                        // Deserialize the item and add it to the list.
                        list.Add(jItem.ToObject<T>(serializer));
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    {
                        throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Unexpected token {0} at {1}", reader.TokenType, reader.Path));
                    }
            }
        }
        // Should not come here.
        throw new JsonSerializationException("Unclosed object at path: " + reader.Path);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // Get the key property name from the underlying name
        var itemContract = serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(typeof(T)) as JsonObjectContract;
        if (itemContract == null)
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("type {0} is not serialized as a JSON object"));
        var keyProperty = itemContract.Properties.Where(p => p.UnderlyingName == KeyPropertyUnderlyingName).SingleOrDefault();
        if (keyProperty == null)
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Key property {0} not found", KeyPropertyUnderlyingName));

        var converters = serializer.Converters.ToArray();
        var list = (IEnumerable<T>)value;
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            var jItem = JObject.FromObject(item, serializer);
            var name = (string)jItem[keyProperty.PropertyName];
            jItem.Remove(keyProperty.PropertyName);
            writer.WritePropertyName(name);
            jItem.WriteTo(writer, converters);
        }
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonReader SkipComments(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment && reader.Read())
            ;
        return reader;
    }

    public static void ReadAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (!reader.Read())
        {
            new JsonReaderException(string.Format("Unexpected end at path {0}", reader.Path));
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can deserialize as follows:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new WhatToMineCalculatorResponseListConverter() },
};
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WhatToMineCalculatorsResponse>(responseString, settings);
```

Notes:

- The base class converter `KeyedListToJsonObjectConverterBase<T>` can be reused in any case where where you are serializing a `List<T>` and the type `T` has a specific property to be used as a JSON object property name.  Simply override `KeyPropertyUnderlyingName` and return the actual .Net property name (not the serialized name).
- The code looks a bit complicated because I made `KeyedListToJsonObjectConverterBase<T>` general enough to handle situations in which the key property is read-only, such as:

  ```
  internal class WhatToMineCalculatorResponse
  {
      readonly string _name;

      public WhatToMineCalculatorResponse(string name)
      {
          this._name = name;
      }

      // I want the key set in this field
      public string Name { get { return _name; } }

      // Remainder of class unchanged
  }
  ```

Working .Net fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SfUN3A).

Comment: Thanks for your custom jsonconverter. it helps me a lots.