# Variable number of JSON properties with dots in the name

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I come across some specially formatted JSON syntaxes from a web. Basically we get variable number of properties with dots in the name. Here are the two obvious cases:

```
case 1:

"data" {
    "SET.Key.count":"0",
    "SET.Value.count":"0",
    ...
}

case 2:

"data" {
    "SET.Key.0":"Key 1",
    "SET.Key.1":"Key 2",
    "SET.Key.2":"Key 3",
    "SET.Key.3":"Key 4",
    "SET.Key.count":"4",
    "SET.Value.0":"10",
    "SET.Value.1":"20",
    "SET.Value.2":"30",
    "SET.Value.3":"40",
    "SET.Value.count":"4",
    ...
}
```

Where count number 4 is an arbitrary number. They can be anything, but key count and value count should be same. "..." means more properties but they can be ignored for this post.

I deserialize JSON streams with Newtonsoft.Json and C#. But I don't have to stay with Newtonsoft.Json. How can I deserialize it into a list of objects (key and value). Any suggestions to handle this kind of JSON properties will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting erros? Are you trying to do anything from the dots? Your question is not very clear.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Looks like you need to use some sort of dictionary, e.g. `public Dictionary<string, string> data { get; set; }`.  See [How can I parse a JSON string that would cause illegal C# identifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24536564/3744182) or [Create a strongly typed c# object from json object with ID as the name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34213724/3744182)

Comment: You can create dictionary from this JSON in C#. You will need to implement your own JsonContractResolver for this. Posting from phone so class name may not be accurate.

Comment: Thanks for the above comments. I have added more explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JsonPropertyAttribute`

```
 [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "user.isSystem")]
 public int IsSystem { get; set; }

 [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "0")]
 public int ZeroField{ get; set; }
```

Comment: This only solves dot notations, but it won't take care of variable numbers of properties. Thanks for the reply.