# Unusual Deserialization Error from JSON to C#

Tags: c#, json

[.Net Fiddle 1](https://dotnetfiddle.net/c4H9XZ)

I have a JOSN received from external API as follows

```
[{
    "assignedto": "MAIN STAFF",
    "createduser": "API-71",
    "departmentid": "1",
    "observations": [{
        "abnormalflag": "abnormal",
        "analytename": "HGB A1C",
        "value": "5"
    }],
    "pages": [],
    "priority": "2",
    "status": "REVIEW"
}]
```

I did a **Paste Special** in Visual Studio and got following classes

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class Class1
{
    public string assignedto { get; set; }
    public string createduser { get; set; }
    public string departmentid { get; set; }
    public Observation[] observations { get; set; }
    public object[] pages { get; set; }
    public string priority { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}

public class Observation
{
    public string abnormalflag { get; set; }
    public string analytename { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

When I do a deserialization, I am getting following error

> Run-time exception (line 24): Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Rootobject' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
>   Path '', line 1, position 1.

**C# Code**

```
public static void Main(string[] args) 
{

    var json = @"[{
                    ""assignedto"": ""MAIN ST (HUB) STAFF"",
                    ""createduser"": ""API-7127"",
                    ""departmentid"": ""1"",
                    ""observations"": [{
                        ""abnormalflag"": ""abnormal"",
                        ""analytename"": ""HGB A1C"",
                        ""value"": ""5""
                    }],
                    ""pages"": [],
                    ""priority"": ""2"",
                    ""status"": ""REVIEW""
                }]";



    Rootobject resultObj = JToken.Parse(json).ToObject<Rootobject>();

}
```

I referred similar questions like [Create a strongly typed c# object from json object with ID as the name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34213566/create-a-strongly-typed-c-sharp-object-from-json-object-with-id-as-the-name) - but that is a different issue.

Any idea how to fix this? Also what is the better way to generate C# classes from   JSON?

Note: I also tried with class I got from http://json2csharp.com/. That also faield - [Fidlle 2](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9YxWKV)

Comment: That's an array of object... not the object itself.

Comment: From the sample provided "Class1" is the root object not the array of "Class1"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use Newtonsoft / Json convert and change this:

```
Rootobject resultObj = JToken.Parse(json).ToObject<Rootobject>();
```

to:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
-- snip --
    var resultObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Class1>>(json);

    Console.WriteLine(resultObj.Count); // 1
    Class1 result = resultObj[0];
    Console.WriteLine(result.assignedto); // "MAIN ST (HUB) STAFF"
```

This will give you a collection of `RootObject`

As @JeffMeracdo states above - you are providing a collection of object and trying to parse as though it is a single object

Comment: I tired this - but not getting the values. Please see https://dotnetfiddle.net/QmxTeb . Any thoughts why it is not giving value?

Comment: Mybad - you are not deserializing to collection of RootObject, you are deserializing to colleciton of Class1. Updated

Answer (score 1):

As @JeffMeracdo states above, try this:

```
List<Example> resultObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Example>>(json);
```

Following **using** statement and package along with **Newtonsoft.Json** Nuget package:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Classes:

```
public class Observation
{
    public string abnormalflag { get; set; }
    public string analytename { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class Example
{
    public string assignedto { get; set; }
    public string createduser { get; set; }
    public string departmentid { get; set; }
    public List<Observation> observations { get; set; }
    public List<object> pages { get; set; }
    public string priority { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```