# List not updating with data from my json file

Tags: c#, json

I'm currently working on an assignment where I need to update a list with data from my json file. However my List keeps coming up as null and I can't seem to find why any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have been trying to look around, but many of the issues I have looked at just mention on how to pull the data not how to resolve this issue.

My classes and code:

```
public class input
{
    DateTime signed;
    DateTime portal;

    public DateTime Signed { get => signed; set => signed = value; }
    public DateTime Portal { get => portal; set => portal = value; }
}

public class InputCollection
{
    private List<input> inputs;

    public List<input> Inputs { get => inputs; set => inputs = value; }
}

using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Dominik\\Documents\\SenateCodingExercise\\CodingAssignment\\CodingAssignment\\input.json"))
{
    //Reads all the data in the file
    string json = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    //converting json string to a serious of objects
    InputCollection inputCollection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InputCollection>(json);
    Console.WriteLine(inputCollection.Inputs.Count);
}
```

My JSON file looks something like this:

```
{
  "Schmidt, Wayne": {
    "signed": "Friday, June 14, 2019 @ 10:58:21 PM"
  },
  "Hertel, Curtis": {
    "portal": "Wednesday, June 5, 2019 @ 10:30:36 AM"
  },
  "Daley, Kevin": {
    "signed": "Tuesday, June 4, 2019 @ 4:07:17 PM"
  }
}
```

Comment: What you *probably* want is to eliminate `InputCollection` entirely and deserialize to a `Dictionary<string, input>` as shown in as shown in [How can I parse a JSON string that would cause illegal C# identifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24536564/3744182) or [Create a strongly typed c# object from json object with ID as the name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34213724/3744182).  But we can't say for sure without a complete, well-formed sample of your JSON.

Comment: OK, deserializing to `Dictionary<string, input>` has a problem, namely that the dates are in the wrong format: https://dotnetfiddle.net/R70kmK.  If I change them to strings then everything works: https://dotnetfiddle.net/26Vvzm.  Do you need to parse then as dates?

Comment: Actually yes it did thank you! Yeah I'll have to parse them as dates, but that I can do.

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize your JSON to a `Dictionary<string, Input>`, as shown in *[Deserialize a Dictionary](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDictionary.htm)* and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24536564/3744182) to *[How can I parse a JSON string that would cause illegal C# identifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24536533/3744182)*, however you will need to make a few modifications to account for your `DateTime` format.

Firstly, modify your `Input` model as follows:

```
public class Input
{
    public DateTime? Signed { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Portal { get; set; }
}
```

Then, deserialize and re-serialize using the settings below:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    // Account for the custom DateTime format.
    DateFormatString = "dddd, MMMM d, yyyy @ h:mm:ss tt",
    // Do not re-serialize null `DateTime?` properties.
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
    // Convert named c# properties -- but not dictionary keys -- to camel case
    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver { NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy() },
};

var inputs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Input>>(json, settings);

var outputJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(inputs, Formatting.Indented, settings);
```

Notes:

- Since some of the JSON entries do not have both `Signed` and `Portal` values, making the c# properties be [nullable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/) allows you to track whether or not a value was actually present in the JSON.
- I modified your class name `Input` to match c# naming conventions.
- Json.NET supports custom `DateTime` formats via the [`JsonSerializerSettings.DateFormatString`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDateFormatString.htm) setting.  Documentation for the various format options can be found in *[Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)*.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oecLsY).