# How to easily create a class for a Json object

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to create a `List` of a class with this object:

```
{
  "801": {
    "Name": "SomeWhere",
    "Lanes": {
      "2": {
        "Ip": "172.23.101.21"
      },
      "4": {
        "Ip": "172.23.101.41"
      },
      "6": {
        "Ip": "172.23.101.61"
      },
      "8": {
        "Ip": "172.23.101.81"
      },
      "9": {
        "Ip": "172.23.101.91"
      },
      "11": {
        "Ip": "172.23.101.111"
      }
    }
  },
  "803": {
    "Name": "OverThere",
    "Lanes": {
      "3": {
        "Ip": "172.23.103.31"
      },
      "6": {
        "Ip": "172.23.103.61"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need it to be able to use it like this: `List<ClassOfJson> jsonData = new List<ClassOfJson>();`

I am using Newtonsoft in C#. What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: You can use [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/) to generate c# classes according to json structure

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [How to auto-generate a C# class file from a JSON object string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21611674/3744182).  Possibly [How can I parse a JSON string that would cause illegal C# identifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24536564/3744182) or [Create a strongly typed c# object from json object with ID as the name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34213724/3744182) also apply.

Comment: https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp (linked to from [How to auto-generate a C# class file from a JSON object string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21611674/3744182)) generates the correct data model.  Do you need that as an answer?

Comment: The root object isn't a list though, it's a dictionary.  Why do you need it to be a list?

Answer (score 5):

You can try to use `Edit->Paste Special->Paste JSON as classes` command in Visual Studio. You can find more helpful tips and tricks in [Visual Studio tips and tricks](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-tips-and-tricks/) article

Comment: Thats a great util!

Comment: Welcome! You can find more tips using this [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-tips-and-tricks/)