# How to handle differing JSON using Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json.net

I am consuming an API response and the response contains a list of items. Here is example JSON

```
{
    "attendeeid": "1",
    "responses": {
    "1": {
        "questionid": "1",
        "fieldname": "1",
        "name": "question?",
        "pageid": "2",
        "page": "Attendee Information",
        "auto_capitalize": "0",
        "choicekey": "",
        "response": [
            " Identify need",
            " Evaluate products and services"
        ]
    },
    "2": {
        "questionid": "2",
        "fieldname": "2",
        "name": "question2",
        "pageid": "2",
        "page": "Attendee Information",
        "auto_capitalize": "0",
        "choicekey": "live",
        "response": "live"
    },
},
}
```

As you can see, the response field in the response can be an object, or a string.

How can I create a POCO object which can be deserialized into? Currently my class is

```
    public class RegistrantInfoResponse
    {
        public string questionid { get; set; }
        public string fieldname { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string response { get; set; }
    }

    public class RegistrantInfo
    {
        public string attendeeid { get; set; }
        public List<RegistrantInfoResponse> responses { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: `response` is not an _object_ or a string, its an _array of strings_ or a single string... To handle that, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994685/how-to-handle-both-a-single-item-and-an-array-for-the-same-property-using-json-n)

Comment: You have interesting JSON coming from the API. Typically the questions would be in an array `[{Question:1},{Question:2}]` and using numbers ("1","2") as property key names doesn't make sense.

Comment: For `responses` use a `Dictionary<string, RegistrantInfoResponse>` or `Dictionary<long, RegistrantInfoResponse> `as shown in [How can I parse a JSON string that would cause illegal C# identifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24536564/3744182) or [Create a strongly typed c# object from json object with ID as the name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34213724/3744182).

Comment: And for `"response"` use `[JsonConverter(typeof(SingleOrArrayConverter<string>))] public List<string> response` from [How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18994685/3744182) as mentioned in comments above.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of modifications you could in your class definition. The RegistrantInfo.responses should be defined as

```
public Dictionary<string, RegistrantInfoResponse> responses { get; set; }
```

This would enable you to use dynamic keys as in the responses (Example, "1","2").

If your observe `RegistrantInfoResponse.response`, it is either an string or an collection of strings. You could use an Custom Converter as provided in the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994685/how-to-handle-both-a-single-item-and-an-array-for-the-same-property-using-json-n) by Brian, which converts a string to a List. This would require to decorate the property with an attribute as the following.

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(SingleOrArrayConverter<string>))]
public List<string> response { get; set; }
```

The complete class definition would be as the following.

```
public class RegistrantInfoResponse
{
    public string questionid { get; set; }
    public string fieldname { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(SingleOrArrayConverter<string>))]
    public List<string> response { get; set; }
}

public class RegistrantInfo
{
    public string attendeeid { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, RegistrantInfoResponse> responses { get; set; }
}
```

Sharing the CustomConverter defined by Brian

```
class SingleOrArrayConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(List<T>));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
        {
            return token.ToObject<List<T>>();
        }
        return new List<T> { token.ToObject<T>() };
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You could now deserialize the json as

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RegistrantInfo>(json);
```

Output Sample

[image]