# How can I get to c# all randomized profile name in json file using NewtonSoft?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

This is my json data

```json
{
  "profiles": {
    "578ed5c5bab24186a6b0f7cd9a952e10": {
      "name": "as",
      "type": "custom",
      "created": "2022-11-02T09:56:53+03:00",
      "lastUsed": "2022-11-02T09:56:53+03:00"
    },
    "41f62754d535457db1c353872a8aafcf": {
      "name": "(Default)",
      "type": "custom",
      "created": "2022-11-02T09:56:50+03:00",
      "lastUsed": "2022-11-02T09:56:50+03:00"
    }
  },
  "selectedProfile": "578ed5c5bab24186a6b0f7cd9a952e10",
  "settings": {
    "enableAdvanced": false,
    "profileSorting": "byName"
  },
  "version": 3
}
```

I want to get random numberized `578ed5c5bab24186a6b0f7cd9a952e10` profile names.
Everytime will be updated this data. That's why, I want to filter to profile names.

I want to get profile names values in profiles.

In normally I can access datas with this way

```
public class _41f62754d535457db1c353872a8aafcf
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public DateTime created { get; set; }
    public DateTime lastUsed { get; set; }
}

public class _578ed5c5bab24186a6b0f7cd9a952e10
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string gameDir { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public DateTime created { get; set; }
    public DateTime lastUsed { get; set; }
}

public class Profiles
{
    public _578ed5c5bab24186a6b0f7cd9a952e10 _578ed5c5bab24186a6b0f7cd9a952e10 { get; set; }
    public _41f62754d535457db1c353872a8aafcf _41f62754d535457db1c353872a8aafcf { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public Profiles profiles { get; set; }
    public string selectedProfile { get; set; }
    public Settings settings { get; set; }
    public int version { get; set; }
}

public class Settings
{
    public bool enableAdvanced { get; set; }
    public string profileSorting { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get without calling `class Profiles`,`class _578ed5c5bab24186a6b0f7cd9a952e10` and `public _41f62754d535457db1c353872a8aafcf`

I want to get with like `public {0} profiles { get; set; }`//after profile firt code class

Comment: Try following :           int length = 32;
            Random rand = new Random();

            var results = string.Join("", Enumerable.Range(0, length).Select(x => rand.Next(0, 15).ToString("x1")));

Comment: What exactly is your problem?  Is your problem that you don't know how to deserialize the JSON shown?  If so, assuming you are trying to deserialize to some c# data model, for `profiles` use a `public Dictionary<string, Profile> profiles { get; set; }` as shown in [How can I parse a JSON string that would cause illegal C# identifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24536564/3744182) or [Create a strongly typed c# object from json object with ID as the name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34213724/3744182).

Comment: Use a dictionary with a string key

Comment: I mean I want to get profile-names without calling. I can do with write directly.

Comment: It is even less clear what you want based on "I want to get profile-names without calling" comment. Please try to think of another way to wording your requirement and [edit] the post to clarify.

Answer (score -1):

you can use a Dictionary

```
public class Root
{
    public Dictionary<string,Profile> profiles { get; set; }
    public string selectedProfile { get; set; }
    public Settings settings { get; set; }
    public int version { get; set; }
}

public class Profile
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string gameDir { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public DateTime created { get; set; }
    public DateTime lastUsed { get; set; }
}
```

or you can create a list of Profile as a profiles

```
    var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);
    Data data = jsonObject.ToObject<Data>();
    data.profiles = ((JObject)jsonObject["profiles"]).Properties().Select(d => ConvertToProfile(d)).ToList();

public Profile ConvertToProfile(JProperty jProp)
{
    var profile = jProp.Value.ToObject<Profile>();
    profile.Id = jProp.Name;
    return profile;
}

public class Data
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<Profile> profiles { get; set; }
    public string selectedProfile { get; set; }
    public Settings settings { get; set; }
    public int version { get; set; }
}
public class Profile
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string gameDir { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public DateTime created { get; set; }
    public DateTime lastUsed { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Duplicates to for this answer are listed in the comments...

Comment: @HereticMonkey Sorry, I am too lazy to read comments. And IMHO the most people are like me, they prefer to see an answer, than to guess what comment is  a correct answer. And I don't see a list in comments for example

Comment: I Used your code and I get this print `ConsoleApp3.Program+Profile` then I edited the this code `public class Root`
      ` public Dictionary<object,Dictionary<object,List<Profile>>> profiles { get; set; }`
           ` public string selectedProfile { get; set; }`
           ` public Settings settings { get; set; }`
          `  public int version { get; set; }`
          Now I get this exception `Error converting value "rf" to type` `System.Collections.Generic.List1[ConsoleApp3.Program+Profile]'. Path` `profiles.ca6957ea93fd465785d9580794f50d0b.name', line 4, position 18.`

Comment: @zouFrax I don't have public Dictionary<object,Dictionary<object,List<Profile>>> in my code.  Where did you get it? My code is public Dictionary<string,Profile> profiles { get; set; }

Comment: I mean ,I used this as your code `Dictionary<string,Profile> profiles { get; set; }` and my print was  `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2[System.String,ConsoleApp3.Program+Profile]` then I edited. to                                                                                                            
 `public Dictionary<object,Dictionary<object,List<Profile>>> profiles { get; set; }`

Comment: @zouFrax I am sorry but I don't know what "print" means and why you need it. This code was tested as well as all my code before publishing, and everything is working properly.

Comment: how can I contact with you

Comment: I sent mail  @Serge